# Swift 2.0 migrating code Error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm having some troubles in code migration for Swift 1.2 to 2.0 and here's what I've been across with:

I've imported some classes written in Swift 1.2 and I've been modifying the code to Swift 2.0 as Xcode keeps warning me about some new features to change... so far so good.

Now I'm stuck with this block of code that I just can't turn around it, no matter what I do I can't fix it unfortunately and now I need your help.

The code is the following:

```
var storeCoordinator:NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: managedModel)

    if storeCoordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil) != nil{
        if error != nil{
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
            abort()
        }
    }
```

and the 2 warnings that Xcode it putting out are

1. 'Binary operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'NSPersistentStore' and 'nil'
2. 'Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled

On the second one I can do a simple do{...try/catch...} method and turn it over but I'm still stuck with the first one.

Thank's for your help in advance.

PS: sorry for my bad English, hope it's understandable.
cheers, Ivan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Swift 2.0**, `addPersistentStoreWithType` returns a non-optional `NSPersistentStore`, so you can't check against `nil`.  If an error happens, it *throws* an error which you must catch:

```
var storeCoordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: managedModel)

do {
    try storeCoordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil)
}
catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: Ohh you're right. I've missed that point completely. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: You're welcome.  Please accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark next it to turn it green.

Comment: you can watch a great video from WWDC 15 [What's New In Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=106)
starting at 28:20 about Error Handling in Swift 2.0

Comment: @vacawama just did ;)

Comment: @hash3r I will do it for sure